# How to change a list within a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've made a parser to extract questions from past exam papers and tabulate how often particular questions/topics arise through the years. It stores the question/topic as a dictionary and the date as a list and is supposed to combine both as follows:

```
questions = {'Question1':['April 2011', 'May 2016'], 'Question2': ['June 2013']}
```

Problem is, I'm unable to update the list of dates within the dictionary. A snippet of my code is as follows:

```
def extract_topics_dates(file):
corpus = ''
topics = []
questions = {}
year = []
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(file, 'rb'))
for page in pdf_reader.pages:
    #For each page, get corpus of text.
    for line in page.extractText().splitlines():
        corpus = corpus + line

    #For each page, extract topics.
    for i in [phrase for phrase in map(str.strip, re.split('\d+\s\s', corpus)) if phrase]:
        topics.append(extract_topic(i))
    topics = [x for x in topics if x is not None]

    #For each page, extract date. 
    year = set([x for x in year if x is not None])
    year.add(get_date(page))

    #For each page, now combine the topic + date.
    for i in topics:
        questions[i].add(year)

return questions
```

Everything in this function works as intended, except the last `questions[i].add(year)` which returns a KeyError. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a list for your key in the dictionary before adding anything to it. Please change that `for loop` to the following:

```
for i in topics:
    if i not in questions:
        questions[i] = list()    
    questions[i].append(year)
```

Or, as suggested by @Jon Clements:

```
for topic in topics:
    questions.setdefault(topic, []).append(year)
```

Comment: Just changed the naming of variables in my code to make it easier for people to understand.

Comment: Or use `dict.setdefault` - ... `for topic in topics: result.setdefault(topic, []).append(year)`... which does exactly what your code is doing here... just more concisely...

Comment: I should have been more clear with my question and code initially. I've updated it now. But thanks for that. Is there a way to 'add' instead of 'append'.

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the comment. I added your suggestion.

Comment: @MonkeyBot2020 You could use a set() (instead of list() ) if you want the add() but then the elements are unordered. Besides, why do you want to use add() so much?

Comment: '#Returns unhashable type: 'set'
        for i in topics:
            if i not in questions:
                questions[i] = set()    
            questions[i].add(year)'

Comment: @MonkeyBot2020 add() will work if you add an element by element but it can't work if you try to add the whole collection at once.

Comment: You're right! I don't need to add, just append. Thank you for your help!